# LTspice: Simulating a Van Der Pol Oscillator

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice

I am trying to simulate the oscillator with an RLC circuit with the initial condition V(V1) = 0 and D(V(V1)) = 0. Since LTspice does not allow initial condition with time derivatives, I set the initial current of the inductor to be -6A. (Initial resistance is 1/3 ohm, and initial current through the capacitor is zero.) The node V(V1) does show a limit cycle behavior, but the amplitude(around 1.2V) is different from the numerical result in Mathematica(2V). I have set all serial and parallel resistance/inductance/capacitance to be zero for the components. Any suggestions on what could be wrong? Thanks in advance for any advice!

[image: schematic]

[image: LTspice result (limit cycle)]

[image: Mathematica result]

Edit: I have also tried using a physical circuitry to initiate my circuit. Yet the voltage of limit cycle is still 1.2V.[image: New schematic]

Also, if I change the resistance in my Mathematica file to be 1/(3*V(V1)*V(V1)-1) instead of 1/(1*V(V1)*V(V1)-1), the voltage response is exactly the same as the result in LTspice. (The first plot in the picture below is when I change the expression of the resistance, and the second plot shows the overlap with LTspice result.)

[image: Overlap when changing coefficient]
On the other hand, all voltage responses scale proportionally as expected. For instance, when the resistance in Mathematica is 1/(V(V1)*V(V1)-4), the amplitude doubles and becomes 4V. The amplitude in LTspice also doubles to be around 2.4V when resistance is 1/(V(V1)*V(V1)-4).

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the implementation in LTspice**

Don't use the options "start up" or "uic" when simulating such circuits. Only use the initial conditions.
Using "uic" makes V(v1) still start at 0V.

[image]

Next, your circuit shows the initial condition `.ic V(V1)=2` but the condition for i(L1) seems not implemented correctly:

[image]

I tested/confirmed by simulation that you made the inductance of L1 equal to `1 IC=-6A`.
So, change the inductance value back to 1. And add the initial condition for L1 to the one for V1 like `.ic V(V1)=2 i(L1)=-6A`

However, this will still not give the same result as Mathematica(2V).

**Regarding the implementation of Van der Pol oscillator**
I wasn't sure if OP's circuit was a good implementation of a Van der Pol oscillator, but a quick KCL shows <strike>it does</strike>:

$$i_C + i_R + i_L = 0$$
$$ C v1' + \frac{1}{R}v1 + \frac{1}{L} \int v1 = 0$$
$$ C v1'' + \frac{1}{R}v1' + \frac{1}{L} v1 = 0$$
Substituting 
$$ C=1 \text{, } L=1 \text{ and } R = -\frac{1}{\mu(1-v1^2)} = \frac{1}{\mu(v1^2-1)}  $$
<strike>yields the Van der Pol equation:</strike>

**EDIT** 
**Regarding the implementation of Van der Pol oscillator**
Noting the other answer I found **the deduction above is incorrect**.
R is dependent to v1, so substition *afterwards* is incorrect.

$$i_C + i_R + i_L = 0$$
$$ C v1' + \frac{1}{R}v1 + \frac{1}{L} \int v1 = 0$$

At this point the substition should be done because, next step, the derivative to v1 is taken, while R depends on v1. For that reason R should be defined as follows:

$$ R = -\frac{1}{\mu(1 - \frac{1}{3} v1^2)} $$

$$ C v1' - \mu(1 - \frac{1}{3} v1^2) v1 + \frac{1}{L} \int v1 = 0$$
$$ C v1' - \mu v1 + \mu \frac{1}{3} v1^3 + \frac{1}{L} \int v1 = 0$$
Taking the derivative to v1:
$$ C v1'' - \mu \text{ } v1' + \mu \text{ } v1^2 \text{ } v1' + \frac{1}{L} v1 = 0$$
$$ C v1'' - \mu (1 - v1^2)v1' + \frac{1}{L} v1 = 0$$

Substituting 
$$ C=1 \text{, } L=1 \text{ and } \mu=1$$
yields the Van der Pol equation:
$$ v1'' - \mu(1-v1^2)v1' + v1  = 0$$

Doing the simulation with `.ic V(V1)=2 I(L1)={-(2*2/3-1)}` will give the correct response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I have also tried initiating it with a voltage source (schematic is attached above), so the initial condition is exactly V(V1) =2 V and I(L1)= -6A, but there is no improvement.

Comment: I think you are right! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

LTspice might have been using the definition R = dV/dI to calculate the response instead of R = V/I.

When R = 1/(V^2-1), I = V/R = V^3-V. Hence if R = dV/dI is actually being used, R = (dV/dt)/(dI/dt) = 1/(3V^2-1) instead, which fits the plot in Mathematica.

I tried a few other values of resistance, such as R = 1/(V^4-V^2) in LTspice, and that corresponds to R = 1/(5V^4-3V^2) in Mathematica.

Comment: I've done a simulation implementing the R with an Arbitrary Behavioral Current Source (B sources) and it gave the same output. So, if the definition of R should be doubted, that still wouldn't solve the same mismatch between Mathematica and the circuit with a B current source.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this will also work (with the corrected expression for R) with .ic V(V1)=2 I(L1)=0 but not with just .ic V(V1)=2. You can, of course, use very small initial values for V(V1) and see the oscillations grow over time to reach the the limit cycle. Using .ic V(V1)=1u I(L1)=0 it takes approx. 35 secs to reach the limit. You can also plot the state-space diagram by plotting d(V(V1)) on the horizontal axis...
[image]